# What accounts to use when installing SQL Server 2008 Developer

Tags: sql-server, installation, development-environment, settings

I am installing SQL Server 2008 Developer here, and on the Server Configuration step of the installation it asks me about Service Accounts. What do I choose here?

I can see the available ones in the screen shot, although on most of them I can only select two or three of those. When I click the *Use the same account for all SQL Server 2008 services* button I can choose between *NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE* and *NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*.

What do I choose here, and why?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From Microsoft:

> Local System account. The name of this
>   account is NT AUTHORITY\System. It is
>   a powerful account that has
>   unrestricted access to all local
>   system resources. It is a member of
>   the Windows Administrators group on
>   the local computer, and is therefore a
>   member of the SQL Server sysadmin
>   fixed server role
>
> Network Service account. The name of
>   this account is NT
>   AUTHORITY\NetworkService. It is
>   available in Microsoft Windows XP and
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003. All
>   services that run under the Network
>   Service account are authenticated to
>   network resources as the local
>   computer.

So unless you need your Dev SQL Server to use Network Services, you can use Local System account.

Update:

To Configure your surface area go Start->Microsoft SQL Server->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Surface Area Configuration.

Thats how you setup for incoming connections. Also make sure the SQL Browser server is running.

I would also recommend either [SQL 2005 for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005-For-Dummies.productCd-0764577557.html) or [SQL Server 2005 Bible](http://www.sqlserverbible.com/books/bible2005.htm) to do some study on some of the basic stuff of SQL Serve. The bible will also go more indepth should you be beyond the dummies type book.

Comment: How do I know if I need to use Network Services? Do I have to use Network Services account if I am going to connect to it from a different computer?

Comment: No. If you sql server needs to connect out. You need to configure the SQL surface area to allow things to connect in.

Comment: For SQL Server Analysis, Reporting and few other I'm getting a third option as well - `Local Service`. Where does this option fit in from SQL Server usage/configuration/setup stand-point? Also for network service, I'm seeing two options in the drop down `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`. Are these two user names equivalent?

Answer (score 27):

If you want to play it safe, make a local account like "SQLServices" on your machine, with no special rights or access. Then install SQL and choose that account, and the SQL installer will add only those rights that the service account requires. I do it this way so that the service account will have only minimal OS rights.

Comment: good advice. will try that the next time I install sql server.

Comment: is this a production environment advice

Comment: No, the question is about developer edition, which cannot be production.