# SQL Server 2008 Installation and Service Account option

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When Installing SQL Server 2008, it asks for Service accounts. Which one to select from the list? and which are the most suitable at the development time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers on this question:
[What accounts to use when installing SQL Server 2008 Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271667/what-accounts-to-use-when-installing-sql-server-2008-developer)

Bottom line is that if you are installing on your dev machine, and are developing client software to talk directly to your local instance of SQL server, you don't really need to worry about the extra stuff mentioned in that question/answer (surface area configuration).

It probably is a good idea to use an account with bare minimum security for your sql server instance. In that case, you can do what the second answer states and create a new user account to use before you install.

If you've already installed, you can do the following:

1. Create your new user account for sql server
2. Add it to the appropriate User group (it will probably be named something like SqlServerMSSQLUser) This will give the user account all necessary rights to run SQL server
3. Update the SQL service to use the new account in the Services tab/option under Administrative Tools

Any time you run into security permissions (say you are exporting files to a share) you can just update the user you created for sql server.